# Connecting azure RDS mysql to azure web app for wordpress blog

Tags: mysql, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

My wordpress connects with **AWS RDS** in localhost but **not** from **Azure** (web app).
It shows `Error establishing a database connection in Azure`.
Whats happening? Am I missing something?
The issue is due to Azure or AWS?

Answer (score 0):

All my Wordpress sites are down hosted on Azure for the 4th time this month. It is only the 9th.

We expect much more from cloud hosting, like if one region goes down another picks up the pieces to limit downtime.

But now do not see this being a reliable host.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the dashboard in your Azure portal for your wordpress site? What does it say?

[This post on the Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-monitor/) site illustrates how it all works.

Essentially what you are looking for at the coded errors (404, etc), and you can also configure Azure to notify you when these alerts go off, via something like e-mail. [This post explains how to do that.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-receive-alert-notifications/)

Finally, [this short video from Scott Hanselman](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-web-sites-endpoint-monitoring-and-staying-up/) illustrates how to do endpoint monitoring and make sense of the dashboard.

With these, you'll be able to determine which service is giving you issues.